# Number of the Sides of a polygon can be seen from the point E.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

Question:

Consider a regular $2n + 1$-gon $P$ in the plane, where n is a positive integer. We say that a point $S$ on one of the sides of $P$ can be seen from a point $E$ that is external to $P$, if the line segment $SE$ contains no other points that lie on the sides of $P$ except $S$. We want to color the sides of $P$ in $3$ colors, such that every side is colored in exactly one color, and each color must be used at least once. Moreover, from every point in the plane external to $P$, at most $2$ different colors on $P$ can be seen (ignore the vertices of $P$, we consider them colorless). Find the largest positive integer for which such a coloring is possible.

My approach and obsevations:
I tried to look generally to the problem, so, I tried to analyze for all polygons.

After drawing polygons $1,2,3,4,5$, I realized that the point $E$ contains in intersection of sides. For example, look at Image 1( 4-th polygon) , when $E$ is place in the intersection of red and green colors, the 2 sides can be visible from E. Same Idea as Image 2 ( 5-th polygon), when the point $E$ is placed in the intersection of orange,red and green lines, it can see all the 3 sides.
After a bit observation, I concluded that when the polygon is even ( therefore in the form of $2n$), the pattern of the maximum number of possible sides that can be seen was $\frac{n}{2}$, and therefore, there were infinite number of even polygons satisfying the condition (Thats why the question asked for odd ones)
I did the same drawing for odd ones, and  the pattern of  the maximum number of possible sides that can be seen was $2n+1-2$. Hence the only n that satisfies was $1$.

The problem is, I don't know how to prove these patterns are true. From diagram (the below ones) I though it had connection with angles and tried to work with the formula $\frac{180(n-2)}{n}$ ( or the degree of angles). But I couldn't find anything usefull with it, can someone give a hint to prove these patterns? ( If they are right)
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 1]

Comment: Does someone have a idea?